# Seven days a week

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, underscore.js

I use the jQuery Calendar with an underscore template and I wanted to put `<li>` tags around each week. This does the trick, but it's awful.

```
<% _.each(days, function(day, index) { %>

    <% if ( index % 7 == 0 && index != 0) { %></li><% } %>
    <% if ( index % 7 == 0) { %><li><% } %>
    <div class="<%= day.classes %>"><%= day.day %></div>
    <% if ( _.size(days) == index + 1 ) { %></li><% } %>

<% }); %>
```

There must be another (elegant) way of doing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting question,

you could definitely place the last `if` outside of the `_.each()`, this would be faster ( fewer `if`s ) and cleaner.

I would also place the first `<li>` outside of the loop and then merge the 2 remaining `if` statements inside the loop.

So, something like this:

```
<li>
<% _.each(days, function(day, index) { %>
    <% if( index && index % 7 ) { %></li><li><% } %>
    <div class="<%= day.classes %>"><%= day.day %></div>
<% }); %>
</li>
```

Personally, I would forego this templating for something like this:

```
function fillTemplate( s ){ 
  //Replace ~ with further provided arguments  
  for( var i = 1, a = s.split('~'), s = '' ; i < arguments.length ; i++ )    
    s = s + a.shift() + arguments[i];  
  return s + a.join("");
}   

var html = '<li>';
_.each( days, function( day, index ){
  if( index && index % 7 )
    html += '</li><li>';
  html += fillTemplate('<div class="~">~</div>', day.classes, day.day );
});
html += '</li>';
```